# Can Aurora PostgreSQL snapshots be migrated/restored to regular PostgreSQL instances?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I've poured over the Amazon RDS documentation but I can't seem to find an answer to this simple question. Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, at least at the time of this post, appears to be no. The `Modify Snapshot` option is grayed out for Aurora snapshots, and when I try to restore one, the DB Engine is set to `aurora-postgresql` and cannot be changed.